do spring boot @Async need to be threadsafe
Our App has spring boot @Scheduled jobs, kafka listeners and @PostMapping Web endpoints publishing an event to the same handler:
@Async
@EventListener
public void handle(someEvent event) throws Exception {
     MDC.put("correlationToken", event.getId();


as all three could in theory call the handle function at the same time, does the handle function need to be multi-threaded, so MDC probably would not work?

The crux is if each channel (web, scheduled jobs and kafka listeners) each has its own thread?

If we converted handle to a plain function call (no async event), will this cause concurrency issues?

Looking at the thread name in the log output, we see something unexpected: all our many different scheduled jobs seem to have the same thread.  This might be because each happens, by luck to finish before the next scheduled action triggers, or may be because they are sharing the same thread (leading to concurrency issues).
I see that the WebServer is using NIO.
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SchedulerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();
    }
    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    }
}


Yes it needs to be thread-safe, no it won't lead to concurrency issues. I don't really understand the whole need for the @Async here anyway (unless you want to execute it in the background). The MDC is thread bound so in theory it should work just make sure you clean up after execution of the method.
